# Responsive Equal height div without specifying the height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for some responsive equal height `div` by just using CSS. I don't want to specify the height. Looking somewhat similar to the image below but both the divs should adjust based on the other div height.

If the left side `div` is long then the right side div should adjust to the left side `div` and vice versa.

Also the right side div has 2 small divs which should also be of same height.

Can this be achieved using only CSS? Or should I make use of JS/jQuery?

[Example here on the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vLpx9k3/)

```css
img {
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid green;
}

.row {
 display: table;
}

.column {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: top;
}

.w100 {
 width: 100%;
}

.w75 {
 width: 75%;
}

.w50 {
 width: 50%;
}

.w25 {
 width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="row w100">
  <div class="column w75">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column w25">
   <div class="col-row">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="col-row">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Your link doesn't work. Please, fix it.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have put a working link now.

Comment: You don't have to create the HTML body element yourself. The output window puts your HTML code inside a body element (besides the fact you didn't close the tag)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [flex-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes), for example:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:row;
}

.column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}
```

And getting rid of the widths the browser does a great job aligning the items:
http://jsfiddle.net/2vLpx9k3/3/

*You may need some prefixes for cross-browser support.*

Comment: Is it possible using just css2? because flex only works on modern browsers. It doesn't support ie9 too.

Comment: @SpiritOfDragon, IE9 isn't modern ;)

Comment: Note that the use of flexbox causes the parent container to collapse when you float child elements and clearfix won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've made something that might possibly be something that you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/2vLpx9k3/4/

It adjusts the widht **and** height of the inner elements based on the outer element.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="right"></div>
        <div class="right bottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    height: 100vh;
}

.left {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 50%;
}

.right {
    background-color: green;
    height: 50%;
    margin-left: 50%;
}

.right.bottom {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Why not? I'm just wondering.. because all browsers except operna mini support it. http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: Because IE support is "Partial". However, its up to the OP project requirements.

Comment: Note that "All other partial support refers to not supporting the "vmax" unit."

Comment: But how can I place 3 images in those 2 divs?